# How to keep 0 value in ggplot2 pie chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 4 elements: x1 x2 x3 x4 and corresponding values:

`overlap_cha <- data.frame( type=rep(c("x1","x2","x3","x4"),c(18,0,91,3)) )`

When I plot pie chart, the `x2` with 0 value will not be shown in the legend.

```
pie <- ggplot(overlap_cha, aes(x = 0, fill = type)) + geom_bar(width = 1)
pie + coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

How can I keep it?

Comment: This is not reproducible.

Comment: @Alex I just edit it.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834382/ggplot2-keep-unused-levels-barplot but I can't quite get those answers to work ATM ...

Comment: @BenBolker it works. But if I do that, I cound not change the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar (but maybe not completely identical to?) [ggplot2 keep unused levels barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834382/ggplot2-keep-unused-levels-barplot) ...

Set up data:

```
overlap_cha <- data.frame( type=rep(c("x1","x2","x3","x4"),c(18,0,91,3)) )
```

Make sure the variable has appropriate factor levels:

```
 overlap_cha$type <- factor(overlap_cha$type,levels=c("x1","x2","x3","x4"))


 library(ggplot2)
 pie <- ggplot(overlap_cha, aes(x = 0, fill = type)) + geom_bar(width = 1)
 pie2 <- pie + scale_fill_discrete(drop=FALSE)+scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)+
         coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

If you want to change the colours, use `scale_fill_brewer` (or you could use `scale_fill_manual` with the `values` argument):

```
 pie3 <- pie +
     scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1",drop=FALSE)+
     scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)+
         coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]

Comment: Actually the `scale_fill_brewer` or `scale_fill_manual` does not work.

Comment: really?  what about my example, which uses `scale_fill_brewer` and seems to work ... ?

Comment: `Error in f(..., self = self) : attempt to apply non-function`. What happend? `pie <- ggplot(overlap_cha, aes(x = "", fill = Type)) + geom_bar(width = 1)  + scale_fill_discrete(palette="Set1",drop=FALSE,labels = nwLabel) + scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)`

Comment: In that example (i.e. to use `palette="Set1"`) you should use `scale_fill_brewer`, not `scale_fill_discrete`