# R - ggplot column or bar graph in 'dodge' position gives me a fat bar when there is no y value for that x

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot percent survival per treatment (percent.o2).  When y == 0% for a treatment, I get a fat bar.  I'd like them to be the same width.  Any advice appreciated.

Data looks like this:

```
> plotData
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   Percent.O2 [7]
   Status        Percent.O2     n percent
   <fct>         <fct>      <int>   <dbl>
 1 Dead          1            144  1.00  
 2 Dead          3            141  0.979 
 3 Dead          7            144  1.00  
 4 Dead          10           105  0.729 
 5 Dead          13            69  0.958 
 6 Dead          Control       12  0.167 
 7 Dead          Control2       2  0.0278
 8 Still_kicking 3              3  0.0208
 9 Still_kicking 10            39  0.271 
10 Still_kicking 13             3  0.0417
11 Still_kicking Control       60  0.833 
12 Still_kicking Control2      70  0.972
```

Here's my code for the plot:

```
> ggplot(plotData, aes(x = Percent.O2, y = percent, fill = Status)) + geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834382/ggplot2-keep-unused-levels-barplot

Comment: I added drop = FALSE and I get the same result.

Comment: ggplot(plotData, aes(x = Percent.O2, y = percent, fill = Status)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)     Produces the same chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `complete` function from the `tidyr` package (which is loaded as part of the `tidyverse` suite of packages) to add rows for the missing levels and fill them with zero (`NA`, the default fill value, would work too). I've also added percent labels on the y-axis using `percent` from the `scales` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

ggplot(plotData %>% 
         complete(Status, nesting(Percent.O2), fill=list(n=0, percent=0)), 
       aes(x = Percent.O2, y = percent, fill = Status)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

[image]