# How to always have fixed number of bins in geom_bar with missing values

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to ask how to always have fixed number of bins in barplots no matter how much variables we have - it must be in bar plot not histogram

for example:

```
DF <- mtcars
ggplot(DF, aes(gear)) + geom_bar()
```

will produce three bars from (3 to 5 values) I would like to also have values 1 and 2 and they must be equal to zero - So we will end up with 5 bar plots. where 2 will be equal to 0 and last 3 values will be equal to values in dataset.

Comment: you'll have to create a data frame first *which contains data for those observations*. How would ggplot know which values are missing? In the toy example, count your gears first. Then you'd need empty rows with gear = 1 and 2 and the count values set to zero. Then use `geom_col` (which is nothing else than `geom_bar(stat = 'identity')` in order to show your count values

Comment: I know that I will always need to see exactly 5 Bars - So I thought it could be done somehow easily

Comment: What I suggested is pretty straight forward? One problem which beginners often have, is that they hesitate to shape their data differently for different purposes. But it's not such a bad thing. It's actually absolutely essential to do so. You have to tell ggplot what you want for your x. If it's always 5 categories, your x column always needs to contain those five categories

Comment: Possible duplicate of? [ggplot2 keep unused levels barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834382/ggplot2-keep-unused-levels-barplot)

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the counts for all missing values of `gear` that you want. One way of achieving that is by using [complete](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html):

```
DF <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by( gear ) %>%
  tally() %>%
  complete( gear = 1:max(gear), fill = list(n=0) )

ggplot(DF, aes(x = gear, y = n)) + geom_bar( stat = 'identity' )
```

Comment: I'd use geom_col instead, as suggested in my comment to the OP. This is essentially the same as `geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

Comment: Oh nice! I didn't know that one. Every day something new. Thanks, @Tjebo! I'll leave my answer as-is so your comment still applies. Anyway, there is some merit in using `geom_bar` as it is widely known and used.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the properties of the x-axis to include 1 and 2. You can add a scale_x_continous and manually define the `breaks` and the `limits`. However, you cannot really see the column for these values because it is a line...

```r
library(tidyverse)

DF <- mtcars
ggplot(DF, aes(gear)) + geom_bar() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:5, limits = c(0.5,5.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Does this help?

Comment: Perfect answer as it doesn't need to modify data. Also, you don't need `tidyverse`, `library(ggplot2)` is enough and `ggplot(mtcars, aes(gear))` will work too.