# How Would I Create Slots On A Histogram For Bins That would Contain No Data

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics

I have a data set that I cut into 7 equal bins using the `cut()` function. I then converted the data back to a data frame using `data.frame()`, then plotted this using ggplot, as seen below:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
data <- runif(n=53,200,1400)
    # converted the data to a value and broke it down from lowest data point to highest data point:
     a-tub.val <- cut(as.numeric(as.character(data)), breaks = seq(0, 1400, by = 200))
    #converted this to a data frame to read into ggplot
     a_tub.dat <- data.frame(a_tub.val)
    # then ran my ggplot code:
     ggplot(data = a_tub.dat) +
        geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=a_tub.val, fill = a_tub.val)) +
        theme(text = element_text(size=20), axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1), legend.title = element_text(size = 12)) +
        ggtitle("Alpha-Tubulin Signals") +
        labs(y="Number in Category", x="Fluoresence bins", fill ="Fluorescence (in thousands)")
```

packages used were `XLConnect` and `ggplot2`

This displays only 4 bars on the ggplot (those that had values), instead of the 7 that I would like to achieve. Would anyone know a way to display those empty bins that contain no data, but should still be viewed on the graph?

[image: Plot displaying 4 bars, however 7 bins were generated]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. I don't think the fact that you are using Excel is relevant to your plotting problem. Just include sample data and ignore where it came from when creating the reproducible example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2 keep unused levels barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834382/ggplot2-keep-unused-levels-barplot)

Comment: okay, I think ive created a reproducible example using set.seed, did this help? relatively new to all of this, trying to help everyone read what I've asked.

Comment: I think you want to add `scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) + scale_fill_discrete(drop=FALSE)` which will add empty bin for (0,200] and update the legend as well

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834382/ggplot2-keep-unused-levels-barplot) by @DanielV, you need to add both a `scale_x_discrete` and `scale_fill_discrete` call so you can add `drop = FALSE` arguments.

```
 ggplot(data = a_tub.dat) +
        geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=a_tub.val, fill = a_tub.val)) + 
        scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) + 
        scale_fill_discrete(drop=FALSE) +
        theme(text = element_text(size=20), axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1), legend.title = element_text(size = 12)) +
        ggtitle("Alpha-Tubulin Signals") +
        labs(y="Number in Category", x="Fluoresence bins", fill ="Fluorescence (in thousands)")
```

[image]