# Plot all levels of factor within a boxplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a boxplot with the iris dataframe. The field Species is factor with 3 levels of setosa, versicolor and virginica. When I filter out setosa, it removes the boxplot from the graph but what I want is for setosa to still be there on the x axis. How can I do this?

```
library(tidyverse)
iris%>%
  filter(Species!="setosa")%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length,fill=Species)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822231/14027775. You can add `scale_x_discrete` with `drop = FALSE` to include all levels of your factor on the x axis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `drop=FALSE` to the `x` and/or `fill` scale and if you are using ggplot2  >= 3.5.0 additionally add `show.legend=TRUE` to `geom_boxplot` (otherwise the key symbol will not be shown in the `fill` legend):

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  filter(Species != "setosa") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot(show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice solution!

Answer (score 3):

You could check which number of level your factor variable is so "setosa" is number 1 in the variable. Now we can use `ggplot_build` to get the data behind the plot to `filter` the group number to remove it from the plot like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
p<-iris%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length,fill=Species)) + 
  geom_boxplot() 

group_setosa = which(levels(iris$Species) == "setosa")

q <- ggplot_build(p)

q$data[[1]] <- q$data[[1]] %>%
  filter(group != group_setosa)

q <- ggplot_gtable(q)
plot(q)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can use `geom_blank` to plot nothing but the scales. This also works without factoring the variable.

```
library(tidyverse)

iris%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length,fill=Species)) +
  geom_blank()+
  geom_boxplot(data = iris[iris$Species!="setosa",])
```

[image: geom_blank]