# ggplot legend in R not recognising aesthetic changes for label category with no data points

Tags: ggplot2, legend, legend-properties, aesthetics

Consider the following image:

[image: R plot]

Although the underlying dataset does not contain values below 0.1 degrees Celsius, I want to and still can force the **legend** to display the *label* and *box* for 'Below 0.1', but ggplot won't recognise the legend colour values I've chosen (instead of black, it's the default grey background colour), nor does it recognise the black bordering I specified for each legend colour box.

A snippet of the code used is below:

```
> colours
[1] "black"          "cornflowerblue" "lightblue"  
> legend_labels
[1] "Below 0.1°C"    "0.1°C to 3.0°C" "3.1°C to 5.0°C" "Missing"       
> legend_limits
[1] "(-Inf,0]" "(0,3]"    "(3,5]"    NA  

    ggplot(
      extreme_days,
      aes(
        .data$Day_number,
        .data$Seasons_ago,
        fill = .data$Temp_category,
        na.rm = FALSE
      )
    ) +
    geom_tile(na.rm = TRUE, width = 1) +
    scale_fill_manual(
      values = colours,
      name = paste(measure_label, 'temperature:'),
      labels = legend_labels,
      limits = legend_limits,
      na.value = na_colour
    ) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(col = "black")))
```

I tried using `drop = FALSE` in `scale_fill_manual()` to ensure all factor levels are used, but it does not work.

If I change `colours` to `c('black', 'cornflowerblue', 'lightblue', 'white')` to include white as well, that doesn't work either.

Also, removing `na.rm = FALSE` in `aes()` in `ggplot()` does not work either.

Importantly, I do not experience this issue with `ggplot2` version 3.4.4. When I upgrade to version 3.5.0, I encounter this issue.

To reproduce the example above, see my code at: https://github.com/a-s-russo/austemp. The relevant functions (in particular, `plot_temperatures()`) are in the `flat_minimal_package.Rmd` file in the `dev/` folder on the `main` branch. The following call to `plot_temperatures()` is used (using the default thresholds of `c(0, 3, 5)`):

```
> devtools::install_github("a-s-russo/austemp")
> library(austemp)
> data('Sydney')
> plot_temperatures(data = Sydney, season = 'winter')
```

Comment: This is most likely due to a change in `ggplot2 3.5.0`. To show the legend key add `show.legend = TRUE` to `geom_tile`. See e.g. my answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78146100/plot-all-levels-of-factor-within-a-boxplot-in-ggplot2/78146210#78146210).